# click submit in html and run php code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am new to html & php and I appreciate your help.  I am trying to accept user input into a webpage and then after the user clicks the submit button, write a new record out to MySQL.  I am using Wordpress so the tags are not exactly textbook.

So my first problem is that the submit button does not appear to execute the php code.  I also would appreciate it if someone could check how I am passing my html field names to the php variables to make sure that I am on the right track.  Thanks for your help!

```
html code to collect user input for fields on the form.....
<?php>
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $FName = $_POST['FName'];
        $MI = $_POST['MI'];
        $LName = $_POST['LName'];
....
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Was my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 12):

I think it can be good to read a bit more about it. Check [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Anyway, you need to say the name of the file to post to: `<input type="submit" action="file.php" name="Submit" />` for example.

And you need to have more inputs than the submit.

Acording to your php you should have as example this in the html:

```
<form action="your_php_file.php" method="post">
 <p>Your first name: <input type="text" name="FName" /></p>
 <p>Your last name: <input type="text" name="LName" /></p>
 <p>Your MI: <input type="text" name="MI" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" name="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

And the php tags are like `<?php` to open, and `?>` to close.

So like:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $FName = $_POST['FName'];
        $MI = $_POST['MI'];
        $LName = $_POST['LName'];
//....
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Actually, in Wordpress, my tags are correct but that is not the issue. I guess at this point what I am not getting is "action="your_php_file.php".  since my php code resides between the [php] and [/php] tags on the page, what file should I be referencing?

Comment: @SandyStokes the name of the file shoul be the same as the file were you have the php.  Let me know if you get it working.

Comment: @zppinto, aceitei o edit. Já agora, sabes da existencia do http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ (em Português)? bemvindo :)

Comment: Sei sim Sérgio, no entanto por uma questão de hábito acedo sempre ao "internacional" :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Your [PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) are incorrect. Use `<?php` and `?>` to tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the code between them. Also, make sure you're closing the [`form` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/form.html#form) (I only see you're opening it) using `</form>` and that you indeed have all those fields contained inside of it.

Comment: Sergio already had that in their post.